# What does #using dll_file do in python

Tags: python, ironpython, dllimport, python-import

I was recently working with a python script that made use of a dll file that was originally written in c++.  The python script had this import line at the top of it:

```
from mycustomdll import *
```

However whenever I ran the script it complained about not being able to find the package mycustomdll.  I looked in another script that also used the dll and saw the following line at the top.

```
#using mycustomdll
```

I added this line to the top of the first file and the python scrypt then ran without issue. A colleague guessed that the #using line was acting sort of as a namespace declaration.  Another possible explanation I have is that it's behaving as a sort of pre-processor directive to the python interpreter.

**What exactly does #using do to expose the dll file to python for importing?**

bonus question(s): Does python even have special keywords like this that override the standard behavior of # as a comment? If so what are they (is there a list somewhere I can peruse?)

We are using a custom subset of pre-compiled IronPython packages for our build environment, some of which may have been written in house so I can't dismiss the possibility this is not standard behavior.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing before. The only times comments are meaningful in Python is at the very top of the file, where the first two lines can have significance. The first line may be a "shebang" line specifying the interpreter to run (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python3`). That's mostly used by external tools to find the right interpreter to use for a script, but also by the `py.exe` launcher for Windows. The first or second line can also specify the source file's encoding, as described in [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). Otherwise a comment is just a comment, I think.

Comment: @Blckknght That's what I thought too!  But I can't argue with what's happening.  It was broken, I added that line and it's not broken anymore.  Like I said it could be something in that custom pre-compiled IronPython interpreter that's being used here, in which case I may have to try to hunt up whomever put that together and ask. Thanks for that link

Comment: If that was standard in IronPython I would expect it to be documented here; https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/lexical_analysis.html but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#using` is just a comment. Even in IronPython.

Comment: Yeah, it must be defined somewhere written into our stuff then, Thanks!